# Galilean transformation and differentiation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, differentiation, galilean-relativity

Given $x=x’-vt$ and $t=t’$, why is $\frac{\partial t}{\partial x’}=0$ instead of $1/v$? $t$ seems to depend on $x’$ because if $t$ changes, $x’$ changes. Also, in this problem, $dx=dx’$ as well, but I do not currently see why that is the case, either.

Source: edx.org / MIT 8.04.1.x / Week 3 / Problem Set 3 / Question 3 / Part A. [link](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:MITx+8.04.1x+3T2018/courseware/week3x/pset3x/3?activate_block_id=block-v1%3AMITx%2B8.04.1x%2B3T2018%2Btype%40vertical%2Bblock%40v-problem15x)

[image: page1]
[image: page2]

Comment: Good idea. Just did!

Answer (score 2):

The equation $x=x'-vt$ describes a coordinate transformation, not something physically moving at some velocity $v$.

With Galilean transformations lengths are invariant, therefore $\text dx=\text dx'$. Also time does not depend on the spatial coordinate system used, so $\frac{\partial t}{\partial x'}=0$